# How to create an interactive graph with filters in Python like the Excel PivotChart

Tags: python, pandas, plot, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization

First let me describe the Excel PivotChart I am trying to reproduce with Python.

Here is the code to generate a sample dataset:

```
# The code should work in Python 3.7 and pandas 0.24 or above
import pandas as pd
years = [i for i in range(2015,2021)]
countries = ['US', 'CA', 'JP', 'MX', 'IT']
months = [i for i in range(1,13)]

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([years, countries, months], names=['year', 'country', 'month'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(idx), 1),columns=['val'], index=idx).sort_index()
```

[image]

I can do `df.to_clipboard()` and paste it in Excel as follows:

[image]

And then I can insert a PivotChart against the data, and configure it in a way such that I can view the monthly line plot by year and by country. This PivotChart is "interactive" in the sense that with the "year" and "country" drop down controls I can conveniently filter the data in any way I want, such as "show all years of JP" or "show all countries in 2020".

[image]

**My question is**:
Is there any easy way to create such an interactive plot in Python? I use Jupyter Notebook to process data and do a lot of exploratory researches like this. I don't like it that I have to copy the data to Excel every time I want to visualize them. In Python I can do dumb things like `df.loc[(2015, 'US'),:].plot()` if I want to filter them to a specific country or year, but it is not as convenient as the PivotChart which has the GUI drop down controls, and it is not easy to share it with my colleagues and let them play around with it.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These options does not completely fullfill your request, but it's a start :

You might want to look at [jupyter_pivottablejs](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/jupyter_pivottablejs) : it provides a simple, yet quite complete, interactive interface equivalent of excel's pivottable by embeding the [pivottablejs](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable) in notebooks (at least in jupyterlab, not sure about classic notebook).

[image: example]

Please note it does not allow for pre-filtering the data interactively. For this, take a look at [qgrid](https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid), which allows interactive browsing dataframes and filtering.

[image: qgrid]